# Is "chip" the singular form of "chips"?

Tags: grammar, word-usage, singular-vs-plural

Consider this sentence:

> There is just one **chip** left in the bag.

Is this sentence correct? *Chips* is the usual term used for the entire amount. I feel that it is a plural-only word, similar to *money* and *water* which are non-countable.

But it obviously *is* countable, so maybe better comparisons are *bread* and *cake* where we can say *a slice of bread* and *a piece of bread*.

Is it possible to say the above sentence and use the word *chip*? If not, is another singular form then possible?

Comment: Dictionaries aimed at learners often contain information regarding the countability of nouns.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that would be a correct way to phrase that sentence.

With water, you'd likely phrase it such as "There's enough water for one more sip" or "There's one more sip of water left"

Answer (score 1):

The sentence is correct and idiomatic. Chips are countable, and when there's only one left in the bag, it's time to open another bag.